# What do you actually mean by interpreting a Java code?

Tags: java

Now i have started learning Java and i am half way through it. From the beginning of attending this course, i commonly hear a word "INTERPRET" your code.
I actually don't use any editors for java programming. I am coding in notepad and have downloaded JDK files. I am using commands to compile and run the code.
So, my doubt here is that what literally is Interpreting?

Comment: Java runs on a virtual machine based on a platform independent byte-code. That byte-code is produced by the `javac` compiler. When you run the byte-code with a Java Runtime Environment, the code is interpreted (evaluated) by the runtime environment and executed on the native CPU. At any point, the JIT compiler can replace the interpreted sections of code with actual native code. So, Java is both interpreted and compiled. Try using the command `javap -v` on any `.class` file to see what the byte-code instructions look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are generally two ways that computer code (written in a language readable by humans) gets translated into machine code: Via a Compiler or an Interpreter.

This is quite a complex topic (I've posted a couple links to additional resources), but the simple answer to your question is that you're using a compiler which means that the ENTIRETY of your java program is translated into machine code instructions BEFORE you run the program. If you were using an interpreter the code would be translated and executed line by line at RUN TIME.

But again this is a big topic for which entire classes are taught. Here are a couple resources to get you started on understanding the difference between compilers and interpreters and some of their trade offs if you're interested.

https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-compiler-and-interpreter.html

https://www.guru99.com/difference-compiler-vs-interpreter.html

Comment: This is basically correct. It might be worth nothing that when you compile your java code, it gets compiled to JVM bytecode, which isn't the same as machine code. At runtime, the JRE + JIT are responsible for generating the actual machine bytecode.